# ¿Cómo puedo obtener la unión de dos tablas relacionadas con un arreglo de uno a muchos?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo las siguientes tablas definidas

```
    CREATE TABLE category (
        id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE
    );

    CREATE TABLE subcategory (
        id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        category_id INT NOT NULL,

        CONSTRAINT FK_subcategory_category_id FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES category(id)
    );
```

Si la información de ellas es la siguiente:

```
    category
    1 | "Botánica"
    2 | "Lencería"
    3 | "Mesa"

    subcategory
    1 | "Plantas y flores"     | 1
    2 | "Materas"              | 1
    3 | "Utensilios de jardín" | 1
    4 | "Lencería de mesa"     | 2
    5 | "Lencería de cama"     | 2
    6 | "Vajilla"              | 3
    7 | "Complementos de mesa" | 3
```

¿cómo puedo hacer una consulta sql para obtener el resultado organizado de la siguiente manera?

```
    { 1, "Botánica", [ { 1, "Plantas y flores" }, { 2, "Materas" }, { 3, "Utensilios de jardín" } ] }
    { 2, "Lencería", [ { 4, "Lencería de mesa" }, { 5, "Lencería de cama" } ] }
    { 3, "Mesa", [ { 6, "Vajilla" }, { 7, "Complementos de mesa" } ] }
```

soy nuevo utilizando mysql y lo estoy implementando con express, he conseguido implementar esta consulta pero no es como lo necesito:

```
    SELECT c.id AS idCat, c.name AS nameCat, s.name AS nameSub
    FROM category c
    LEFT JOIN subcategory s ON c.id=s.category_id
```

Comment: Y no lo vas a lograr.. no debes tratar de solucionar problemas de vista con SQL, que es un lenguaje que trabaja con conjuntos y su teoria. No vas a poder mostrar la informacion asi.

Comment: Tal como dice @gbianchi, no podrás (con SQL) asignar a un campo un valor de lista. Los registros en SQL están diseñados para tener **un solo** valor por campo. Tu planteamiento pide que el tercer campo del registro devuelto contenga una lista de valores. Me parece que la construcción de esa lista la puedes hacer fuera de SQL, es decir en tu aplicación. Obtienes los datos tabulados por subcategoría y luego filtras el resultado para crear la estructura que estás buscando. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Esto puedes lograrlo utilizando la función [`group_concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) de mySQL, que te devuelve una lista de el o los campos que le indiques.

Por ejemplo:

```
select  c.id AS idCat, c.name AS nameCat, group_concat(s.name) AS nameSub
  from category c
       left join subcategory s ON c.id=s.category_id
 group by c.id, c.name
```

Te devolverá en cada registro un ID y nombre de categoría, con una lista de las sub-categorías en el campo nameSub.

```
    1 | Botánica  | Plantas y flores, Materas, Utensilios de jardín
    2 | Lencería  | Lencería de mesa, Lencería de cama
    3 | Mesa      | Vajilla, Complementos de mesa
```

Si quieres incluir el ID y el nombre de cada sub-categoría en dicho campo, puedes concatenar los valores antes de armar la lista, algo como lo siguiente:

```
select   c.id AS idCat
       , c.name AS nameCat
       , group_concat(concat(s.id, '-', s.name)) AS nameIdSub
  from category c
       left join subcategory s ON c.id=s.category_id
 group by c.id, c.name
```

Que devolverá algo como:

```
    1 | Botánica  | 1-Plantas y flores, 2-Materas, 3-Utensilios de jardín
    2 | Lencería  | 4-Lencería de mesa, 5-Lencería de cama
    3 | Mesa      | 6-Vajilla, 7-Complementos de mesa
```